# php not executable on server

Tags: php, executable, httpd.conf

So I am installed php but now whenever I go to the url in the browser, e.g. test.php, it is not an executable file and it prompts me to download it. I have this in my httpd.conf file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

And this is what I have had on my servers in the past that has allowed me to have my php execute. Any idea what I could be doing wrong? Here is a link to the url:

http://108.166.126.202/test.php

Thanks!

Update: The issue was in my browser, not on the server. I opened the url in Firefox (instead of chrome) and it gave me no issues.

Comment: `HERE I IS` -- has it been repaired since posting?

Comment: @sarnold, it was an issue with my browser. Not a server issue.

Comment: wow, crazy, I've never seen that be anything other than a server misconfiguration. Good thing Rick aimed you at the right path.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me, perhaps you should try it with a different browser?
Sounds like a faulty setting on your side and not the server's.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot! I tried it in firefox and it worked fine. You saved me hours of torment! Guess now I just have to find out what's wrong with chrome...many thanks!

Comment: @srchulo - were you originally using a local file url? did you restart apache? what did you do different that made it work? other people could learn from your mistake/experience

Comment: @HorusKol, I did not change anything. I loaded the url in Firefox and it worked for me. It was not a server issue, but a local browser issue. It will not load correctly in my chrome browser, but it will load fine in others.

Comment: @srchulo - hmm... technically, changing the browser is changing something ;) it sounds like there could be mime-type issue - Chrome is not reading your output as text/html (or whatever) for some reason, and prompting the download

Comment: @HorusKol, I guess it is an issue, but it is not one I have fixed, so as of now I have nothing to report :p